# numpy array error " Error('X.shape[0] and y.shape[0] should be the same"

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I was trying to convert my data file to LibSVM file format and got this error:

```
ValueError('X.shape[0] and y.shape[0] should be the same  got 1L and 3997L instead.',), <traceback object at 0x000000000DC9E608>
```

I have a file feature of one dimension and the label file, the error occurred with the feature file (train data). I am using the same code for different types of feature and have no error since it is 2D. Can you please help me.

```
user_train=np.loadtxt(user_train)
train_label=np.loadtxt(train_label)
print('imputing training data ...')

imp=Imputer(missing_values='NaN',strategy='mean',axis=1)
imp.fit(user_train)
user_train=imp.transform(user_train)
print(user_train.shape,train_label.shape)
print('normalizing training data ...')
print(user,i)

normalizer=preprocessing.Normalizer().fit(user_train)
user_train_nor=normalizer.transform(user_train)
print('writing trainiing data')

output=(save_fea+'%s_tag_train_nor.txt'%(user))

svm_rank_format=dump_svmlight_file(user_train_nor,train_label,output,zero_based=False)
```

The shape of the array as print: ((1L, 3997L): user_train(the feature 1D), (3997L,): label also 1D)

Comment: Looks like you just need to reshape your array from (1,3997) to (3997,)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> X.shape[0] and y.shape[0] should be the same got 1L and 3997L instead.

It means `user_train.shape[0]` and `train_label.shape[0]` should be the same value but in your case it is 1 and 3997.

In general, if you have `N` number of training examples and `M` number of features (in your case, it is `train_label`). Then the dimension of `X` (in your case, it is `user_train`) should be `N X M` and dimension of `y` should be `N X 1`.

You can verify their dimension before training your model to avoid such errors.

> Solution

In this case, you can use [reshape()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) or [transpose()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.transpose.html) to convert to required dimension.

I guess in your example, dimension of `user_train` is `1 X 3997` and dimension of `train_label` is `(3997,)`. So to match the dimension, you can either reshape or transpose the n-dimensional array `user_train` to solve the issue.

Comment: @Samah best way to thank is through accepting the answer.